# include accents in bibtex file

Tags: bibtex

How would I include the following name into a Bibtex document:

J\ddot{a}rvinen

This returns an error saying that you cannot use mathmode in this file. How would I alter this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\ddot` is the math mode accent and can't be used in text (unrelated to bibtex) for text you want `\"{a}` -- or, better for bibtex, `{\"a}`.

Comment: Is there a reference sheet for these?

Comment: any latex manual should have this  eg table 2.2 in the "not so short introduction to latex" (`texdoc lshort` in many didtributions)